# Python 3.X Selenium Headless Chrome Error 1016

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I want to run headless Chrome but it keeps crashing with the following error:

[0814/155351.062:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1016)] Lost UI shared context.

I have no idea what is going on here. My code is simple and works with the GUI.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless') # Enable headless
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') # Required as I am on Windows

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromepath,chrome_options=options)   #chromepath is a raw string to the driver

driver.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki')

driver.quit()

print('Successfully opened and closed headless Chrome')
```

All dependencies are current:

Chrome version: 68.0.3440.106(Official Build)(64-bit)

Selenium: 3.14.0

Chromedriver: 2.41